# cannot stop bootstrap modal from closing on button click after failed validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked a few times but using e.preventDefault() or event.preventDefault() did not seem to work for me.

This is the code snippet:

```
$(".save").on("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    var noImages = $('input[name="pics[]"]:checked').length;
        if(noImages > 1) {
            alert("Only one image allowed");
        } else {
        // allow selection and close modal
```

If more than one image is selected in the modal, it alerts the message but closes the modal which it shouldn't. The modal should only close if the user selects one image and then clicks on "save".

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the closing of your modal, you should remove `data-dismiss="modal"` from your html. The issue then will be triggering the close when you want to.

Bootstrap gives a handle for this with `.modal('hide')`. For example, in your save click handler:

```
$(".save").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var noImages = $('input[name="pics[]"]:checked').length;
    if(noImages > 1) {
        alert("Only one image allowed");
    } else {
        $(e.target).closest('.modal-dialog').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

If you modal has an id, you can also find it that way instead of `closest`.